# Is deprecated getContent still the only option for PopupControl objects in JavaFX 8?

Tags: java, javafx-8

When I wrote an application under the 2.2.6 version of JavaFX I had a series of popup-type display objects implemented using classes that extended PopupControl. What was odd at the time was how the only way I could add Nodes to the control was to call getContent() to get the ObservableList of Nodes and then add to it. But even then getContent was listed as deprecated and it suggested that it would be replaced in the next version which I took to be JavaFX 8.

So now I have JavaFX 8 and I've loaded the code in NetBeans 8.0. The Javadoc popup for getContent() still states "Deprecated. This is an internal API that is not intended for use and will be removed in the next version". But there do not appear to be any new methods in the PopupControl class that I could use in its place. Am I missing something?

This is a simplified example of the only way I've been able to make things work so far:

```
public class PopupPane extends PopupControl
{  
    public PopupPane()
    {
        HBox PopBase = new HBox();
        PopBase.getChildren().addAll(Button1, Button2, Button3);
        this.getContent().add(PopBase);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a non-deprecated option:

```
public class PopupPane extends PopupControl
{  
    public PopupPane()
    {
        HBox PopBase = new HBox();
        PopBase.getChildren().addAll(Button1, Button2, Button3);
        this.getScene().setRoot(PopBase);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry: was short of time and trying to provide a quick answer. I clarified it.